# Make two side-by-side html elements adapt their widths so (text-)content gets same height

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

Is there a way to make two html elements sit side by side and have the available width automatically distributed between them in a way so that each element's content gets the same height?

#### Example:

Consider having 2 p-tags where one consists of 200 characters and the other of 100 characters. I want them to sit side by side and together fill 100% of the parent container. Their respective widths should be automatically distributed so that each p-tag consists of equally many lines.

#### Example with pictures

What I don't what:
[Two boxes with text that has same width but different heights of the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofbwx.png)

The width of the two boxes should be distributed so it looks more like this: [Two boxes with text that has different width but same heights of the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGUj4.png)

---

**Is this possible to achieve with css-grid, flexbox or some other method?
If so, is it expandable to apply to mixed content with both images and text?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, flex's `stretch` value *try its' best* to keep height same, though if two paragraphs have too many words difference, the height will not be the same

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  }
  
 p {
  background-color: #ccc;
  }
  
 p:last-child {
  background-color: #999;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ip</p>
  <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. How does this work on mixed content (headings, pictures etc.) and how does it handle child elements. Is there a way to achieve this with e.g. two divs that each contains an img, h1 and p tag?

Comment: @dealerpriest I think so, just wrap children in div and adjust layout in that div